Grouping dates from rows
I have information/data like this:

How can I group dates for a given employee from several lines to one, if the dates are consecutive?
I tried AI, but I still have problems with formatting dates and writing them, and I cannot change it because it is the result of an earlier action.

the macro would run in the active sheet,
applies only to columns A-D
the result would be transferred to the P-S columns, which need to be cleared first
my data has no headers
rows with single dates remain as they are
MS Office 2016 for small office

I would like:


It is not good to place pictures... Can you place the data in something editable, please? Are existing date from column ”D:D” formated as Date?

Its not formated as a date. Example file with more data in rows [wetransfer]: we.tl/t-SHKpLPGlFM

How close have you got? If you post the code you've tried, perhaps it would be quicker to spot an error than write the code for you?

Which is your date standard format? Something as „mm/dd/yyyy”...

My standard date is dd/mm/yyyy. I finised with AI on [wetransfer]: we.tl/t-Ag7YMlasWX

Should the consecutive date belong to the same month?

No, dates grouped only in a given month. When another month begins, we start over.

Please, test the code I posted and send some feedback. I could see your answer related to date belonging to the same month after I prepared that part of the code. If (by mistake, or because of a different reason) there are date in different months both dates will be returned, separated by " - "

Please, try the next code. It uses a dictionary and some arrays. Working mostly in memory and dropping only the processed array result, it should be very fast even for large ranges. It assumes that for the same user all data in columns A, B and C columns are the same:
Sub GrupingByUser()
  Dim ws As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, arrIT, arrFin, firstDate As Date, lastDate As Date
  Dim i As Long, j As Long, dict As Object
  
  Set ws = ActiveSheet
  lastR = ws.Range("D" & ws.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on D:D
  
  arr = ws.Range("A1:D" & lastR).Value 'place the range in an array for faster iteration
  
  Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.Dictionary")     'set the necessary dictionary
  For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
    'if the first columns concatenation does not exist as a key, add it to dictionary:
    If Not dict.Exists(CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)) Then
        dict.Add CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3), Array(arr(i, 4)) 'the item placed in an array
    Else
        arrIT = dict(CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)) 'extract the existing item in an array
        ReDim Preserve arrIT(UBound(arrIT) + 1)                           'redim the item array preserving existing
        arrIT(UBound(arrIT)) = arr(i, 4)                                  'place the date as the last array element
        dict(CStr(arr(i, 1)) & "|" & arr(i, 2) & "|" & arr(i, 3)) = arrIT 'place the array back as the dict item
    End If
  Next i
  
  'redim the final array:
  ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To 4)
  
  'process the dictionary data and place them in the final array:
  For i = 0 To dict.count - 1
    arrIT = Split(dict.keys()(i), "|") 'split the key by "|" separator
    For j = 0 To UBound(arrIT): arrFin(i + 1, j + 1) = arrIT(j): Next j   'place each element in its column
    
    firstDate = MakeDateFromStr(CStr(dict.Items()(i)(0))) 'extract first date
    
    arrIT = dict.Items()(i)
    lastDate = MakeDateFromStr(CStr(arrIT(UBound(arrIT)))) 'last date

    If Month(firstDate) = Month(lastDate) Then 'if both date are inside the same month:
       If lastDate = firstDate Then            'if only one date:
            arrFin(i + 1, 4) = firstDate
       Else                                    'if more dates (in the same month)
            arrFin(i + 1, 4) = Format(Day(firstDate), "00") & " - " & Format(lastDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
       End If
    Else                                        'if not in the same month:
       arrFin(i + 1, 4) = Format(firstDate, "dd/mm/yyyy") & " - " & Format(lastDate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
    End If
  Next i
  
  'drop the processed array result, at once:
  ws.Range("P1").Resize(UBound(arrFin), UBound(arrFin, 2)).Value = arrFin
  
  MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub

Function MakeDateFromStr(d As String) As Date
   MakeDateFromStr = CDate(left(d, 2) & "/" & Mid(d, 4, 2) & "/" & Right(d, 4))
End Function

I tried commenting every code line, so it should be easy understood, I think. If something not clear enough, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.
CStr(arr(i, 1)) has been used to overpass potential errors in the first column (#N/A). Even if they are written as string, VBA still understands them as error (for instance, #N/A is understood as Error 2024). It is easy to be written as #N/A, but I do not think to be necessary...
Please, send some feedback after testing it.

after run it's something going on here: firstDate = MakeDateFromStr(CStr(dict.Items()(i)(0))) 'extract first date' I have got first msg about not defined function.

@KMYozz Ups... It looks I missed posting the function. I will do it now.

@KMYozz OK, posted the function, too. Please, test the updated code (only containing the function able to extract date from string)...

its working... but in the result i got this: "07-08-2024 - 07-12-2024" and shoud be this: "08-07-2024 - 12-07-2024" or simple if it is possible: "08 - 12/07/2024". In this example month (7 - July) is on the second place (EU format date)

@KMYozz I asked you which is your local/standard date format... You probably, should say that the string date you have is in a different format. I mean, I thought that "08.07.2004" is formatted as "dd.mm.yyyy". Should I understand that it is in fact formatted as "mm.dd.2024"? If so, no difficult to adapt the function, but you should mention that... Unfortunately, your example has date not exceeding 12 as the first part and I couldn't deduce the meaning of each group...

I'm sorry, I think we misunderstood each other. I thought you were asking how I write the date when I use it. However, you probably meant formatting the cell with the date and saving it. The cell itself was not formatted - "General" and a date in the cell is a text where is day / month / year.

@KMYozz You answered the same ("dd/mm/yyyy"). And the date in example could not mean something else than "dd.mm.yyyy", I think. Otherwise, "8 - 12.07.2024" looks to mean from 8 to 12 of July. Am I wrong? If not, the date is built using this format, only changing the date separator (/ instead of .)... Since in my localization "12.07.2024" has a meaning and Excel recognizes it as Date ("dd.mm.yyyy") I do not receive any error. In my case it is interpreted as date in both cases. If you have AnyDesk and availability to remotely connect to your computer, I will maybe better understand it...

@KMYozz It was here an invitation (from your side) for a chat room. I was there, I wrote something but you were not. Now I cannot see your comment...

Sorry, I had to leave. I'm at work and I use my free time as much as I can. But I think I dealt with it by analyzing the code, because after changing the line to: MakeDateFromStr = CDate(Mid(d, 4, 2) & "/" & Left(d, 2) & "/" & Right(d, 4))
works as I expected.

@KMYozz This only means that the text date is in format "mm.dd.yyyy". I asked you specifically on this aspect, too in my above comment. But if so, what meaning should have  "8 - 12.07.2024"? Not from 8 to 12 of July? If so, the first part should represent the day... It's strange.

I know it strange. I search in regional settings but there is everything ok, Id try to check cell formating and change for short date. After this change in macro it automatlicaly see this as a real date for excel too. The meaning is as You wrote: "8 - 12.07.2024" is 8 to 12 of July 2024. Anyway, it works. Thank you for your patience and sorry for the confusion, but I always have problems with dates and times (with macros] in Excel, even though I try to ensure that the data is in the correct format.

@KMYozz Never mind... It is good that it works for you, even if I cannot understand why... I forgot specifying the next aspect: The code will work even if the respective persons are not sorted! But the old date to be first and the most recent to be last... The code can be adapted to also extract first and last analyzing the dictionary item, after making all of them Date... Excel keeps the Date as Long numbers...

A rational function, but I don't know if it is needed because what I receive from the previous macro is always sorted from the newest to the oldest. and I usually make a summary for one entire month, selecting the period from the beginning to the date I indicate.

@KMYozz I do not have a problem with that... What I tried emphasizing is the fact that if the new entries are input of the last empty row it is no need of any sorting. The code will work as you need. If there is "a previous macro" it does not need to sort... If I would know what that previous macro does, maybe the integration of this sub will be benefic. Also in terms of code speed...

Hi, I found a bug. Is it possible to solve this? If you have a person who has entries with dates from 11.07.2024 to 26.07.2024 and there are for e.g. 2 days missing between these dates, the macro will still show in the results as one range. 11 - 26.07.2024, instead of 2 ranges, e.g.: 11 - 15.07.2024 and 18 - 26.07.2024

@KMYozz I am afraid, it is not any bug... The above code answered the question exactly as it was formulated. What did you mean by "the dates are consecutive"? Then, if you understood now that the question is not very well formulated, this is a different issue. Of course, the problem can be solved but the dates analyze is more complicated. For such a case it would be good to place another question showing the above code and explain what else do you need related to non consecutive ranges processing. If you tag me (here) and send a link to the question, I will try helping, if available.

@KMYozz If not availability, somebody else will certainly solve the requirement... Anyhow, you must clearly explain what is to be done and also specify if more than two such date intervals would be possible. The analyzing algorithm must be designed in a simpler way or in a more complicated one, in case of undefined number of intervals.

I apologize, but sometimes I use a translator and maybe this is also the reason for the differences in constructing queries and comments. Thank you for your reply and advice on how to proceed next. I'll do it after work, calmly, from my home computer.

@KMYozz I offered myself to help you, if you tag me here showing the link to the new question. It only happened I could see the question. And I placed an answer....
